# XML para DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, xml, tipagem

Estive pesquisando em como passar os dados contidos em um XML para um `DataTable` e encontrei a seguinte [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7801673/5913854).

Dúvida:

Ao fazer dessa forma, o método `theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);` é capaz de identificar os tipos dos dados no XML? Ou ele criará todas as colunas do `DataTable`como `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegue, pelo menos em certas situações. Se tiver a informação do *schema* pode ser melhor. Existe uma sobrecarga do método [`theDataSet.ReadXml()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataSet_ReadXml_System_String_System_Data_XmlReadMode_) que permite isto usando usando a enumeração [`XmlReadMode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.xmlreadmode?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Deve escolher o que melhor te atende. Cuidado para não confiar demais na inferência, teste muito todas situações.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Xml/Read.cs).

Answer (score 2):

é possível sim, tudo depende da criação do XML, utilizo uma api na empresa quem e retorna dados da seguinte maneira

```
<xs:element name="LedgerID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="sUnit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="sSize" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="Area" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
```

Com estes dados basta usar o `theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);` e os dados já virão formatados, tudo depende da pré formatação do seu XML